# Gearing up for RIFT end game

Tags: rift

Currently RIFT is on the 1.7 update/event.  I recently hit 50 and I was wondering what would be a good way to get geared for raids?  I don't know many of the dungeons/instant adventures/etc, because I haven't really done any of them (I did Iron Tomb a few times).  Can anyone suggest a good way to get geared up for raids, dungeons, etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fresh 50 you have a number of activities to pick from to gear yourself up.

- **Expert dungeons**. These will reward you with Plaque of Achievement and/or Mark of Ascension, which you can use to buy armor sets. You also have a chance of getting some nice gear pieces from the bosses you kill.
- **Water Saga quest chain**, which starts in the dungeon Abyssal Precipice. Some of the quest rewards are equal to entry level raid gear.
- **World invasions** in high level zones. These will reward you with Inscribed Sourcestone, which you can use to buy equipment up to raiding level. Instant adventure will also give you more of these.
- **Chronicles** for a few extra Plaques and some lower quality loot.
- **PvP/Warfronts** if you're into that. PvP gear lacks focus/hit, but is otherwise very good for PvE as well. Be warned though, it's a tough life PvPing as a fresh 50.

Comment: I have witnessed the destruction of PvP as a newly entering 50... It did not last long.  I believe it was the expert dungeons that I tried once but I did not have the hit rating to go into them.

For the Water Saga quest chain, do you have to start that in the normal Abyssal Precipice or does it have to be expert?

I have been also doing the World Invasions in Shimmershand as well as the Instant Adventures, but that seems to take a while to get enough currency to get a piece of gear.

Also, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Chronicle loot, runes (enchants), and possibly some crafted gear can be stepping stones to get the hit rating needed. I believe either version of AP works to get the quest started. It's true that Inscribed stones take a while to get, and as such they might not be your main way of gearing up but a nice complement. They're extra important for aquiring good essences to put in your planar focus.