# Rift Level 50 Expert Dungeon Gear Requirements

Tags: rift

I hit 50 the day of 1.8 (healing cleric), and I'm wondering if I can do expert dungeons with my tank buddy.

The Internet seems outdated on just how endgame progression works since the expert tiers merged in 1.7. In fact, I can't find a single resource that's been updated since the change.

The in-game Toughness stat mouse-over text recommends 100 toughness for experts. However, this would imply we'd have to grind the last three normal mode dungeons for Plaques ~70 times (assuming daily random bonus each time) to buy the entire T1 set of plaque gear before we could start experts. This seems excessive.

Could you guys confirm what toughness/hit/focus stats we actually need to do random experts?

Note: I saw [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61921/gearing-up-for-rift-end-game), and while that tells me all the things I can do, it does not tell me if I'll be able to complete the content (assuming a bit of competency). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question on [Reddit's Rift subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Rift/comments/sk3o5/expert_dungeon_gear_requirements/) and got a lot of really great responses.

I'll summarize here:

Minimums to be remotely effective (and to queue for randoms, thanks SirCobalt!):

- Normal Dungeons: 0 toughness/0 hit/0 focus
- Expert Dungeons 100 toughness/100 hit/100 focus
- T1 Raids (Drowned Halls, Gilded Prophecy, River of Souls, Greenscale Blight) 150 toughness/200 hit/200 focus
- T2 Raids (Hammerknell Fortress, Rise of the Phoenix) 200 toughness/300 hit/ 300 focus
- T3 Raid (Infernal Dawn) 250 toughness/400 hit/400 focus

For the raids, you really want 20 more hit/focus to ensure you never miss / get resisted. Akylios in T2 requires 360 hit/focus to never miss / get resisted.

To help the tank get to 100 toughness so we can start experts, he should get a [Incandescent Indominatable Rune](http://rift.zam.com/en/recipe/854337939/), +20 Toughness on chest. Transplanar + that rune is 84 Toughness, so you don't need anywhere close to a full Plaque gear set to reach toughness minimum.

Direct healers are unique in that they do not need focus/hit/toughness to succeed. They should just ensure they hit their stat cap (400 Wisdom for Clerics).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the 'required' stats are not actually required to enter the dungeons, but only what they believe you should have to adequately perform your role.  If you have below that amount then you will not hit mobs, or get crit more often (in the case of a tank), etc.

Now I believe that if you do NOT meet those requirements then you CANNOT queue for a random group in expert dungeons.  I tried that and it would not let me queue.

If you are certain you and your group/friends can run through the expert dungeons with your current gear then I would say you should definitely give it a shot.  Worst that happens is you wipe a few times, or you can't complete it and then you have to go through the oh-so-fun process of grinding for badges and whatnot.

EDIT:  Here is a link to a wiki page that has information on the dungeons and their 'required' stats:
http://telarapedia.com/wiki/Dungeon